# Подсчёт времени выполнения bash-скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, дата

Имеется лог куда пишется время начала и окончания работы скрипта. Всего 3 запуска в сутки, соответственно имеем 6 таймстепов. Таймстемп вида 2022-11-18T05:20:01. Задача: посчитать время работы каждого запуска в отдельности и записать это в файл. На данный момент удалось сгрепать время в виде 05:20:01 (дата в данном случае не имеет значения) и конвертировать все 6 значений в секунды.

Соответственно, теперь  задача как-то вычислить разницу между вторым и первым,четвёртым и третьим, шестым и пятым, затем конвертировать в %H:%M:%S и уложить в файл. На данный момент удалось добиться вывода в файл шести значений в секундах.

Непонятно как им присвоить переменные, чтобы потом вычислить разницу, может можно как-то решить другим образом. Спасибо...

```
#!/bin/bash
file="time.log"
IFS=$'\n'
for var in $(grep -o '[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' $file | tail -n6)
do
echo $var | awk -F: '{ a=$1*60+$2 ; if (NF<3) print a ; else print a*60+$3 }' 
done
```

Здесь выхлоп всего этого:

```
19201
19789
20511
21901
21901
22164
```

Comment: А не рассматривали вариант считать время работы в самом скрипте, что бы не заниматься парсингом лога?

Comment: Предположим что скрипт очень тяжелый, начал работу 2022-11-18T05:20:01 а закончил 2022-11-19T05:20:02, дата в данном случае не имеет значения?) Если отбросить дату, получится что скрипт очень шустрый, справился за секунду.

Comment: Я сделал в скрипте подсчёт общего времени работы (сам процесс занимает около полутора часов), а что касается промежуточных запусков, то там всё несколько сложнее: их стартуют другие процессы и я пока даже не смог отследить какие. Поэтому решил попробовать пока так...

Answer (score 3):

как-то вы сильно усложнили себе задачу

> имеем 6 таймстепов. Таймстемп вида 2022-11-18T05:20:01
> ... конвертировать все 6 значений в секунды

нужно просто перевести время в `Unix Timestamp`([Unix-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)) которое уже будет в секундах, а после просто отнять `Unix Time` начала и конца выполнения скрипта

Получить `Unix Timestamp` из даты довольно просто

```
$ date +%s --date "2022-11-18T05:20:01"
1668741601
```

пример того как из лога добыть `Unix Timestamp` и посчитать разницу

**time.log**

```
2022-11-18T05:20:01 текст1 лога
2022-11-18T05:21:01 текст2 лога
2022-11-18T05:21:11 текст3 лога
2022-11-18T05:21:51 текст4 лога
2022-11-18T05:22:01 текст5 лога
2022-11-18T05:22:23 текст6 лога
```

получаем `Unix Timestamp`

```
$ awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' time.log
1668741601
1668741661
1668741671
1668741711
1668741721
1668741743
```

с помощью `awk` посчитаем разницу в секундах

```
$ awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' time.log | awk 'NR%2==1{x=$0}NR%2==0{print $0-x}'
60
40
22
```

с переводом итоговых секунд в формат `%T`, аналог `%H:%M:%S`

```
$ awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' time.log |awk 'NR%2==1{x=$0}NR%2==0{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%T")}'
00:01:00
00:00:40
00:00:22
```

если же предполагается что работа скрипта может продлится больше чем день, то

```
$ awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' time.log |awk 'NR%2==1{x=$0}NR%2==0{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%j.%T")}' | awk -F. '{print $1-1" дней, "$2}'
0 дней, 00:01:00
0 дней, 00:00:40
0 дней, 00:00:22
```

Comment: А как-то можно сделать вывод в %H:%M:%S?

Comment: @Plastikman можно поступить стандартно, деля и вычитая, например чтобы получить количество дней, сравниваем наше число секунд с 86400 (это 24*60*60), если оно меньше значит целых дней нету, то есть 0, если больше то делим нацело и узнаём скока дней, а остаток подобно дням уже дальше разглаживаем на часы и минуты, что останется записываем в секунды. Но это всё долго и скучно, можно немного схитрить и преобразовать с помощью всё той же утилиты `date`, добавлю позже в ответ.

Comment: а что, одним вызовом интерпретатора awk обойтись нельзя? надо именно три процесса запускать? как-то вы сильно усложнили себе задачу.

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin `а что, одним вызовом интерпретатора awk обойтись нельзя?` - при желании конечно и в один `awk` можно уместить но это сильно усложнит логику, а так вышло довольно оптимально как по сложности реализации так и по количеству составляющих; `надо именно три процесса запускать?` - если с учетом работы скрипта больше 24 часов, то да три, хотя если судить по одному из коментов автора - `сам процесс занимает около полутора часов` то в принципе можно ограничится и первым вариантов где используется тока два `awk`.

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin вы написали - `как-то вы сильно усложнили себе задачу.`, я так понимаю это попытка поддеть меня отзеркалив моё первое приложение в ответе на вопрос, но если честно это выглядит немного глуповато на фоне вашего же ответа, два запущенных процесса - `awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' time.log |awk 'NR%2==1{x=$0}NR%2==0{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%T")}'` vs ваш код `cat log | xargs -n1 date +%s -d | sed 'N;s/\n/+/;s/^/-/' | bc | while read s; do TZ=UTC printf "%(%H:%M:%S)T\n" $s; done` , скока там у вас запущенных процессов ? и это с уже обрезанными входными данными.

Answer (score 1):

Предисловие:

- В первую очередь хотелось бы отметить, что время работы скрипта лучше реализовывать в оригинальном скрипте.
- Если это невозможно, то нужно в скрипте сбора информации о времени работы следует сделать проверку на активность основного скрипта, так как если во время выполнения будет только запись о старте, скрипт проверки времени запуска вернет не корректную информацию.

---

Один из вариантов решения на bash

```
#Входящий файл
input=file.log
#Исходящий файл
output=runtime.log
while read line; do
#Генератор, для дальнейшего получение четности строки
    i=$((${i:-0} + 1))
#Проверка генератора на целочисленное деление с остатком
    if [[ $(($i%2)) -ne 0 ]]; then
#Если остаток не равен 0, то записываем переменную запуска
        startTime=${line/ *}
    else
#Если строка четная, то проводим вычисления
#Переводим в секунды и отнимаем стоку завершения скрипта от запуска
        diffTime=$((`date -d "${line/ *}" +%s` - `date -d "${startTime}" +%s`))
#Переводим секунды и печатаем в формате: hh:mm:ss
#tee -a допишет в файл лога и выведет в консоль, если нужно просто записывать в лог, то можно использовать >>
        printf "execute time: %02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$((diffTime/3600))" "$((diffTime/60%60))" "$((diffTime%60))" | tee -a ${output}
    fi
#передаем в цикл последние 6 строк из файла
done< <(tail -n6 $input)
```

file.log:

```txt
2022-12-01T05:22:01 yyy
2022-12-01T05:22:23 xxx
2022-12-01T05:20:01 yyy
2022-12-05T05:21:01 xxx
2022-12-06T05:21:11 yyy
2022-12-07T05:21:51 xxx
2022-12-08T03:25:01 yyy
2022-12-08T09:55:23 xxx
```

output:

```txt
execute time: 96:01:00
execute time: 24:00:40
execute time: 06:30:22
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
intervals="00:15:12
00:04:06
00:00:50"

common_time=0

while read -r -u 3 time; do

    seconds=$(date -d "1970-01-01 $time" -u +"%s")

    common_time=$(( $common_time + $seconds ))

done 3< <(printf '%s\n' "${intervals}" )

echo $(date -d @$common_time +"%T" -u)

# 00:20:08
```

Answer (score 1):

добавлю ещё один вариант.

пусть имеется вот такая информация:

```
$ cat log
2022-11-18T05:20:01
2022-11-18T05:21:02
2022-11-18T05:22:01
2022-11-18T05:23:03
2022-11-18T05:24:01
2022-11-18T06:25:04
```

а вот однострочник, преобразующий эту информацию в требуемый формат:

```
$ cat log | xargs -n1 date +%s -d | sed 'N;s/\n/+/;s/^/-/' | bc | while read s; do TZ=UTC printf "%(%H:%M:%S)T\n" $s; done
00:01:01
00:01:02
01:01:03
```

---

пояснения.

для начала преобразуем в секунды с начала «unix-эпохи» (1 января 1970):

```
$ cat log | xargs -n1 date +%s -d
1668738001
1668738062
1668738121
1668738183
1668738241
1668741904
```

затем преобразуем эти шесть строк в три арифметических выражения:

```
$ cat log | xargs -n1 date +%s -d | sed 'N;s/\n/+/;s/^/-/'
-1668738001+1668738062
-1668738121+1668738183
-1668738241+1668741904
```

и вычислим эти выражения:

```
$ cat log | xargs -n1 date +%s -d | sed 'N;s/\n/+/;s/^/-/' | bc
61
62
3663
```

а полученные секунды преобразуем в часы:минуты:секунды (подсмотрел [здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507666/110559)):

```
$ cat log | xargs -n1 date +%s -d | sed 'N;s/\n/+/;s/^/-/' | bc | while read s; do TZ=UTC printf "%(%H:%M:%S)T\n" $s; done
00:01:01
00:01:02
01:01:03
```

Comment: В конечном итоге я взял за основу вариант @Zt.

Answer (score -1):

В конечном итоге я взял за основу вариант @Zt. Он работает. Вот что получилось:

```
#!/bin/bash
log="/var/log/log.log"
output="/var/log/output.log"


# Time in seconds
timesec=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n20 | \
awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' | awk 'NR==1{x=$0}NR==6{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%s")}')
echo "Full time in seconds $timesec" >> "$output"


# First run
run1start=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | awk '(NR == 1)')
echo "1'st run start $run1start" >> "$output"

run1end=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | awk '(NR == 2)')
echo "1'st run end $run1end" >> "$output"

run1=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | \
awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' | awk 'NR==1{x=$0}NR==2{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%T")}')
echo "1'st run duration: $run1" >> "$output"


# Second run
run2start=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | awk '(NR == 3)')
echo "2'nd run start $run2start" >> "$output"

run2end=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | awk '(NR == 4)')
echo "2'nd run end $run2end" >> "$output"

run2=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | \
awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' | awk 'NR==3{x=$0}NR==4{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%T")}')
echo "2'nd run duration: $run2" >> "$output"

# Third run duration
run3start=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | awk '(NR == 5)')
echo "3'rd run start $run3start" >> "$output"

run3end=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | awk '(NR == 6)')
echo "3'rd run end $run3end" >> "$output"

run3=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | \
awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' | awk 'NR==5{x=$0}NR==6{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%T")}')
echo "3'rd run duration: $run3" >> "$output"

# Time of run
run=$(grep -o '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' "$log" | tail -n6 | \
awk '{system("date +%s --date "$1)}' | awk 'NR==1{x=$0}NR==6{system("date --utc --date=@"$0-x" +%T")}')
echo "Total runs duration: $run" >> "$output"
```